# One-to-many relationship with wtforms_alchemy.ModelFieldList does not update children

Tags: sqlalchemy, wtforms

Below is a form that populates an empty parent object and creates its children.  It was necessary to manually invoke a ModelFormField, which was a minor annoyance.  It works great.  However, when I use the form to do an *update*, only the object is updated -- the children are created fresh.

What is the correct way to propogate an update to the children in this framework?  Effectively, I'd like to the two print statements below to print the same thing.  I'd be especially grateful if the form would create (delete) children if the formdata had extra (was missing) data for the children.

```
from multidict import MultiDict
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from wtforms_alchemy import ModelFieldList, ModelForm, ModelFormField

Base = declarative_base()

class Child(Base):
  __tablename__ = "child"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String)
  parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id"))

class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = "parent"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String)
  children = relationship(Child)

class ChildForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Child

class ParentForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Parent
  children = ModelFieldList(ModelFormField(ChildForm))  # annoyed!

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Form data
formdata = MultiDict({"name": "Foo", "children-0-name": "hotdog"})

# Create initial object
question = Parent()
form = ParentForm(formdata, obj=question)
form.populate_obj(question)
if not form.validate():
  raise RuntimeError(form.errors)
session.add(question)
session.commit()

# prints: "(1, 1)"
print((question.id, question.children[0].id))


# Retrieve object and update with same data
question_get = session.query(Parent).get(question.id)
form = ParentForm(formdata, obj=question_get)
form.populate_obj(question_get)
if not form.validate():
  raise RuntimeError(form.errors)
session.add(question_get)
session.commit()

# prints: "(1, 2)", want it to print the same as above
print((question_get.id, question_get.children[0].id))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In digging through the code, it looks like object ids are expected for updates. Therefore, one must use a form on update which includes the id and pass around the ids.

```
--- orig.py 2018-05-01 20:51:09.000000000 -0700
+++ fixed.py    2018-05-01 20:56:16.000000000 -0700
@@ -4,6 +4,7 @@
 from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
 from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
+from wtforms import IntegerField

 from wtforms_alchemy import ModelFieldList, ModelForm, ModelFormField

@@ -24,6 +25,7 @@
 class ChildForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Child
+  id = IntegerField()  # Optional field used in update operations.

 class ParentForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
@@ -53,7 +55,11 @@

 # Retrieve object and update with same data
 question_get = session.query(Parent).get(question.id)
-form = ParentForm(formdata, obj=question_get)
+child_id = question_get.children[0].id
+formdata_update = MultiDict({"name": "Foo",
+                             "children-0-id": child_id,
+                             "children-0-name": "pizza"})
+form = ParentForm(formdata_update, obj=question_get)
 form.populate_obj(question_get)
 if not form.validate():
   raise RuntimeError(form.errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice sleuthing.  Still this seems rather cumbersome.  Have you subsequently found a easier way to do an update on a form with a one to many relationship?  WTForms are supposed to save developer time.  But this seems like more overhead than doing it without WTForms.